# REGEX - Match special character anywhere in the string

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, vb.net, validation

I am not a regex guy, so I need a little help, just cant get my head around this...

I am writing registration page and using asp.net validators. I need a regex validator to match a special character anywhere within a word, so it will satisfy requirement which says that "ID must have at least one special character." Allowed characters are: 
!   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -
.   /   :    ;  <   =   >   ?   @   [   \   ]   ^
_   `   {   |   }   ~

Once again, I am a junior, and having problems with wrapping my head around this stuff at this moment...

For now I have

```
[\[\]\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\\~`!@#%&-_+={}'""<>:;, ]{1,}
```

but it matches numbers as well for some reason, and sometimes don't match characters in the beginning of the word...

So, please, if anyone could help me with that...

Comment: I hate websites that require ids and passwords to contain special characters.

Comment: Just a side-note: if you're suing ASP.NET Membership, you could use the [`MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.minrequirednonalphanumericcharacters.aspx)-property to ensure that special chars are entered in the password.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - noooo, not suing Microsoft :)  The reason why I cant use this in membership provider, is because this validation will be optional - it can be turned on or off, depending on the client needs...and we will not be able to enforce it for all clients of our app. Thanks for the side note though..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape '-' and '!'

```
[\[\]\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\\~`\!@#%&\-_+={}'""<>:;, ]{1,}
```

Comment: yeah..i overlooked that... however, for some reason string as "asdf3!#" doe not want to validate using your expression...maybe it has something to do with .net...

Comment: Looks like you need to escape ! as well

Answer (score 4):

It would be easier to do the opposite

`^[0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]$`

it has a special character if it doesn't match

Comment: cant use this, it will match characters that are not defined in characters set that i need, such as spades or currency signs...

Comment: in that way, maybe this woud be better
[^a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: Even better would be to exclude white spaces too `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]`

Comment: Not really, if you are dealing with unicode characters or even ascii-extended, this wouldn't be the same at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not a asp.net or validation expert. But, character classes only need certain characters escaped like `[]`. The dash `-` represents a range of characters. If used as a literal, it can be escaped and put anywhere, or can be put at the beginning or end of the class (`[-aa]` or `[aa-]`) and be treated as a literal. Also, a caret at the beginning of the class, denotes a 'negative' class meaning, any characters but these (`[^not me]`).

There may be other constructs in classes with special syntax unique to a particular engine (.NET may be this way, I'm not sure). Certain sequences trigger a subclass too I guess.

Here are my test case's with asp.net validator using your special characters. They may be relavent I am not sure. Both seem to not validate blank input, this may not be a regex thing.

```
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Input is not valid." 
        ValidationExpression="^.*[\[\]^$.|?*+()\\~`!@#%&\-_+={}'&quot;&lt;&gt;:;,\ ].*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

This one seems to take care of a security issue if thats relavent. Note the `<+'alpha char'` where 'alpha' refers to a range of valid unicode characters according to some standard I think.

```
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Input is not valid." 
        ValidationExpression="^(?!.*&lt;(?:/|[A-Za-z_:])).*[\[\]^$.|?*+()\\~`!@#%&\-_+={}'&quot;&lt;&gt;:;,\ ].*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Just disregard if this is way off.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim this down a bit and match character ranges. For example, this matches all special (and printable) characters (including unicode) characters:

```
[^\p{L}]
```

I suppose if you need to match 1 or more, as is specific to your case, then this would work as well (Note that the `+` regex operator is shorthand for `{1,}`

```
[^\p{L}]+
```